# Dynamic Code in C

Tags: c, dynamic

I have the following codeblock I'm using for German verb drills:

```
if (strcmp(*option, "sein") == 0)
    *option = linie.sein;

if (strcmp(*option, "haben") == 0)
    *option = linie.haben;

if (strcmp(*option, "possessiv") == 0)
    *option = linie.possessiv;

if (strcmp(*option, "reflexiv") == 0)
    *option = linie.reflexiv;

if (strcmp(*option, "accusativ") == 0)
    *option = linie.accusativ;

if (strcmp(*option, "dativ") == 0)
    *option = linie.dativ;
```

However I would like to condense it to something like:

```
*option = linie.(*option);
```

Or perhaps:

```
*option = linie.(*option)();
```

Unfortunately neither of these work. Any ideas?

Edit @dasblinkenlight:

```
typedef struct
{
    char subjekt[20];
    char sein[20];
    char haben[20];
    char possessiv[20];
    char reflexiv[20];
    char accusativ[20];
    char dativ[20];
} satz;

satz linie =
{
    .subjekt = "",
    .sein = "",
    .haben = "",
    .possessiv = "",
    .reflexiv = "",
    .accusativ = "",
    .dativ = ""
};

char *option = argv[1];
```

Comment: Please show definitions of `linie` and `option`.

Comment: Containers and loops. You should really learn the "0-1-Many Rule".

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible in C, as it has no reflection or dynamic code capability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing compile-time and runtime options. In C, you can't use an identifier directly from a string got at runtime. However, you can bring your comparaisons into an opaque function.

```
char *f(const satz *linie, const char *option)
{
    if (strcmp(option, "sein") == 0)
        return linie->sein;
    else if (strcmp(option, "haben") == 0)
        return linie->haben;
    else if (strcmp(option, "possessiv") == 0)
        return linie->possessiv;
    else if (strcmp(option, "reflexiv") == 0)
            return linie->reflexiv;
    else if (strcmp(option, "accusativ") == 0)
        return linie->accusativ;
    else if (strcmp(option, "dativ") == 0)
        return linie->dativ;
    else
        return NULL;
}

*option = f(&linie, *option);
```

Comment: You're right about mixing comile-time and runtime strings Kirilenko. I  would say this is as good as it'll get. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Kirilenko's answer is a good one and works well for short structures like yours.  However, for longer structures, maintaining all of the strcmp calls can be cumbersome.  To solve this, you can define a relationship between the keyword you are trying to match and the offset of the corresponding element in your structure.

```
struct relation
{
    char keyword[20];
    int offset;
};
```

Then you can use the offsetof macro (in stddef.h) to link the keyword to its position in your structure.

```
#define REL_LEN (7)

struct relation rel[REL_LEN] = {
    {"subjekt", offsetof(satz, subjekt) },
    {"sein", offsetof(satz, sein) },
    {"haben", offsetof(satz, haben) },
    {"possessiv", offsetof(satz, possessiv) },
    {"reflexiv", offsetof(satz, reflexiv) },
    {"accusativ", offsetof(satz, accusativ) },
    {"dativ", offsetof(satz, dativ) }
};
```

Finally, the function to retrieve your character string using the mapping above could look something like this.

```
char *lookup_keyword(const satz *linie, const char *option, 
                     const struct relation *rel, size_t rel_size)
{
    int i;
    char *pchar = (char *)linie;

    for (i=0; i<rel_size; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(option, rel->keyword) == 0)
        {
            pchar += rel->offset;
            return pchar;
        }
        rel++;
    }
    printf("Error: no mapping found matching %s!\n", option);
    return "";
}
```

And you can invoke it like so

```
char *option = argv[1];

printf("Result for %s: %s\n", option, 
       lookup_keyword(&linie, option, rel, REL_LEN));
```